# How do I change the text in the export format dropdown on SQL Reporting server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am looking for a way to change the text in the export format dropdown of a report on the SQL Reporting server (2005). For example, currently, one of the dropdown items is named: **Web archive**. I would like to change that to say: **Web archive (.mhtml)**.

I've done some searching on google, but couldn't find any satisfactory answer. I have also searched through both config files in the Report Services folder of the instance in question, but found nothing.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

You can use the OverrideName xml tag to rename the display name of an export format. See this [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281.aspx).